# Mostrar resultados de una búsqueda en un JTable

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, java-swing, jdbc

Tengo esta desktop app que realiza la búsqueda de una entidad llamada **User(id,name,surname,password,admin)** id,name,surn.... son "attributos fijos":

**Tabla users:**

```
CREATE TABLE users

    (
      id serial NOT NULL,
      name character(20),
      surname character(20),
      password character(15),
      admin boolean,
      CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
      CONSTRAINT users_id_key UNIQUE (id)
    )
```

Cada usuario tiene una relación uno-a-muchos con la entidad **Attribute(id,name,value,type)** o "atributos adicionales" las tablas que representan Attribute:

```
CREATE TABLE users_attributes
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character(25),
  type character(20),
  CONSTRAINT users_attributes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT users_attributes_name_key UNIQUE (name)
)

CREATE TABLE users_attributes_values
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  user_id serial NOT NULL,
  attribute_id serial NOT NULL,
  value character(40),
  CONSTRAINT users_attributes_values_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT users_attributes_values_attribute_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (attribute_id)
      REFERENCES users_attributes (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT users_attributes_values_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

La búsqueda puede ser **realizada** con 2 queries: una con el operador logico **AND** y otra con **OR**:

```
private final String SQL_GET_ALL_USERS_BY_PARAMETERS_AND = "SELECT id,name,surname,admin FROM users WHERE id=? AND name=? AND surname=? AND admin=? ORDER BY id";
    private final String SQL_GET_ALL_USERS_BY_PARAMETERS_OR = "SELECT id,name,surname,admin FROM users WHERE id=? OR name=? OR surname=? OR admin=? ORDER BY id";
```

El usuario del app elije cual query usar con los radio buttons respectivos.

Ejemplo **id,name,surname,role son atributos fijos** ,

**Country,Age,City,Salary,Profession,IBAN son atributos adicionales**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Llamada del metodo de búsqueda:

```
UserService userService = new UserService();
userService.setFoundUsersInTable(searchTable, inputUser, operator);
```

La función usa el metodo **resultSetToTableModel()** de la libreria **rs2xml.jar** para poblar la **JTable**:

```
@Override
    public void setFoundUsersInTable(JTable table, User user, String operator) {
        switch (operator) {
        case "AND":
            try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_GET_ALL_USERS_BY_PARAMETERS_AND)) {
                pstmt.setInt(1, user.getId());
                pstmt.setString(2, user.getName());
                pstmt.setString(3, user.getSurname());
                pstmt.setBoolean(4, user.getAdmin());
                ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case "OR":
            try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_GET_ALL_USERS_BY_PARAMETERS_OR)) {
                pstmt.setInt(1, user.getId());
                pstmt.setString(2, user.getName());
                pstmt.setString(3, user.getSurname());
                pstmt.setBoolean(4, user.getAdmin());
                ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

La aplicación funciona con la búsqueda en base de los atributos fijos de cada usuario como en el ejemplo pero no encuentro un modo para poder realizar la búsqueda en base a los atributos adicionales, por ejemplo lograr buscar un usuario en base al attributo adicional:Country.

Como puedo implementar este tipo de búsqueda?

Comment: No acabo de entenderlo: ¿Funciona cuando usas OR pero no cuando es con AND?

Comment: Con el AND no regresa nada por que considera los valores en blanco.

Comment: no te va a regresar nada debido a que el and es una condición que necesita valores y tu los pasas en blanco por ese motivo no te regresara ningún registro les estas pasando 4 datos con el and y solo 1 con texto si prueba la misma sentencia en tu BD veras que tampoco te devolverá nada

Comment: Si de eso no hay duda, el problema es como usar también los atributos extra, ya tengo una respuesta para mi pregunta, la publicare mañana.